# Return не выводит значения после компеляции

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Дорый день. В качестве примера хочу привести часть кода:
[image: Результат после компиляции]
}

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Return - не выводит значения, вне зависимости это будет boolean, String, int, double, etc.
В связи с чем не могу понять результать после компеляции.
До обновления IDE на прошлой неделе все работало корректно.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: И не должен, `return` не имеет никакого отношения к выводу, которого в вашем коде вообще нет.

Comment: return - это оператор возврата из функции, он и не должен ничего никуда выводить. Ваш вопрос непонятен, попробуйте переформулировать.

Comment: @tym32167
Я имею в виду что при return false/false, -1, -1.0, и т.п. Я не вижу что именно произолшло. Я приложил скрин, возможно он чем-то поможет.

Comment: `System.out.print(isPrime(2));` ?

Comment: @tym32167, Ух, как-то аж стыдно стало. Да, спасибо.

Comment: Ничего страшного, бывает. Хорошо, что разобрались.

Answer (score 0):

для вывода значения в консоль, если я правильно понял, используй System.out.print(isPrime(2));

Answer (score 0):

Как понимаю, вы вызываете метод, соответственно, нужно вывести ответ, который придёт.

```
public class Main{ // Класс, в котором вызываете

public void main() {
System.out.println(isPrime(5)); // System.out.println(); - это то, что выводит на экран консоли. 
    }

public static boolean isPrime(int n) { // Метод, который вызываете в Main
    if (n == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!